# Controls that don't have ViewState

Tags: asp.net, controls, viewstate

I am very new to Asp.Net.

Almost all the controls i have seen till now has **ViewState**.

So, my question is Are there any controls that don't have **ViewState** ? What are they.

I have googled, but din't find the correct solution.

Thank you !!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every control has ViewState because that is where all attribute values are stored.

To avoid ViewState you can disable it on the control (`EnableViewState=false`) and make sure when you set any properties (like `Text`, `Visible` etc.) you do that yourself on every postback (so that ViewState is not needed) - so in events like `Page_Load` instead of `Button_Click`.

Comment: +1 Knaģis . Additionally , I want to know if I have 10 control in my web page and I set `EnableViewState=false` to some or all , will the performance be vary ?